# How do I use variables declared in one method, in another method.

Tags: java, class, variables, methods

So I have a method that looks like this:

```
public Maze(String[] textmaze, int startRow, int startCol, int finishRow, int finishCol){
    int numRows = textmaze.length;
    int numCols = textmaze[0].length;
    int [][] x = new int[numRows][numCols];
    }
```

So I want to use the variables x, numRows and numCols in other methods however numRows and numCols needs the String textmaze which must be passed in as a parameter and the main method where this method is called is in another class which I'm not allowed to modify. So how can I use those variables in other methods?

Comment: 1- That's not a method, it's a constructor; 2- In that case, have you thought of providing getters for them...?

Comment: I've never used constructors like this in java and I also don't know what getters are.

Comment: A getter is an accessor method, it's simply a method that allows you to "get" a value from an object.  While you may never have written one, I'm sure you've encountered them in one form or another

Answer (score 2):

Since `Maze` is a constructor, and you want to use the variables in other parts of the class, you should make the variables instance fields instead, for example...

```
private int numRows;
private int numCols;
private int [][] x;

public Maze(String[] textmaze, int startRow, int startCol, int finishRow, int finishCol){
    numRows = textmaze.length;
    numCols = textmaze[0].length;
    x = new int[numRows][numCols];
}
```

This will allow you to access the variables from within THIS (`Maze`) classes context.

Depending on what you want to do, you could also provide accessors for the fields to allow child classes access to them (using `protected` to prevent other classes from outside the package from accessing them or `public` if you want other classes to access them)...

```
public int getNumRows() {
    return numRows;
}
```

Take a look at [Understanding Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) and [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for more details

Comment: I now have another problem. So for some reason when I compile it, I keep getting an error that says it cannot find the symbol on the line numCols = textmaze[0].length; and the arrow is pointing at the dot in textmaze[0].length. Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: `textmaze` is one dimensional array, either the parameter is wrong or you're trying to do something which is not achievable...